# xamarin forms geolocator plugin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am working on a xamarin forms application and i want to use the geolocator plugin.

the problem im having is that the geolocator plugin code gives me errors. this is the code im using is this:

```
 private async void BtngetLocation_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
      locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

      var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
 }
```

the error im getting is by the GetPositionAsync(timeoutmilliseconds : 10000)
this is the error : The best overload for 'GetPositionAsync' does not have a parameter named 'timeoutMilliseconds'

the version i am using for the plugin is version 4.1.1. what confuses me is when i downgrade to version 3.0.4 the parameter 'timeoutmilliseconds' works and it doesnt give me errors. but when i run the application it crashes.

please help i dont know what to do.

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`GetPositionAsync` nows uses a `TimeSpan` instead of milliseconds.

```
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null, IncludeHeading.IsToggled);
```

Docs: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/

All of his plugins (going into the major version of 4, thus a breaking change version) are now starting to use `TimeSpan`, you can read about those changes to another one:

re: https://montemagno.com/connectivity-plugin-4-0-important-and-awesome-changes/